# Why can't I access method from controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nomethoderror

first of all I'm creating a rails app and I'm trying to separate some logic in my model and putting it a separate class for handling this logic.

So I created a new file in my app/models directory named upload_processor.rb with this content:

```
class UploadProcessor

  def self.process_file(filename)
    Rails.logger.debug "This is a test for separating logic #{filename}"
  end
end
```

And I call this method from my controller like this:

```
UploadProcessor.process_file!("filename")
```

So when I want to check if this works I get the errors from rails:

NoMethodError in ArticlesController#upload_file => undefined method `process_file!' for UploadProcessor:Class

So is there anybody who can tell where I did something wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Typo. `process_file` v. `process_file!`.

Comment: @Mori Thanks wasn't paying so much attention apparently, kinda a new to ruby / rails Thanks!

Comment: Also, that's not a model--I'm not convinced it belongs in the `model` directory.

Comment: True, but where should I put these kind of classes then?